# How to prevent from losing entered input fields in PHP form

Tags: javascript, php, forms, post

I have a form with bunch of input fields. When a user click submit, I pass the form to itself.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="?import" method="post" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

When `$_GET['import']` is set, I check if all the input fields have right format. If not, I alert with an error message and redirect to a previous page, so that users can correct the input fields. `echo"<script> alert('$msg'); history.back(); </script>";`

The problem here is, when they are redirected to the page, they lose all the input they have entered. (it doesn't happen in chrome as it probably has a nice feature to prevent this but it does happen in firefox). What is the smart way to prevent this in php?

Thanks!

Comment: they will be in the post array

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do, but if you use AJAX, instead of normal form submission, you can avoid losing form data.

Comment: Actually if you could post the full code, it'll be great. You seem to mix javascript and PHP in arguably a conventional way (esp the redirecting), thou it might be irrelevant to the result you wan to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Try using php to inject values to javascript

Put this at the end of your file

```
<script>    
    document.getElementById("myInputField").value = <?php echo $_GET['import']; ?>
</script>
```

You might want to put check if $_GET (or $_POST, depending which one you are using, otherwise just use $_REQUEST) is empty or not first, but it seems you already know how to check it

Comment: can you really do <?php ?> Inside <Script>

Comment: Yes you can the `<?php ?>` will be executed first. You might need to rename your file to .php though if it isn't already

Comment: dang. Added my question as an Answer. Lol. so .PHP won't work? Do you call this php javascript injection?

Comment: Haha .. depending on how purist you are. But yes, I would call this PHP javascript injection. I wouldn't say using PHP won't work, it really depends on how you check it and redirect it. In this case OP is writing redirection in Javacsript via PHP, this way achieving the result via PHP only won't be achieveable as redirection via Javascript is already detached from the PHP environment

Comment: I ended up using $_COOKIE instead.. ;(

Comment: Be careful when using $_COOKIE as it is not permanent. If the user clear the cache, it'll be gone. Or if it's left too long it may be gone too. Not to mention it maybe able to be hijacked.

But hey, if that works for you it could be good enough :)